# Replace repeated special characters with a single special character

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am attempting to use `REGEXREPLACE` in `Google Sheets` to remove the repeating special character `\n`.

I can't get it to replace all repeating instances of the characters with a single instance.

Here is my code:

```
REGEXREPLACE("Hi Gene\n\n\n\n\nHope","\\n+","\\n")
```

I want the results to be:

```
Hi Gene\nHope
```

But it always maintains the new lines.

```
Hi Gene\n\n\n\n\nHope
```

It has to be an issue with replacing the special characters because this:

```
REGEXREPLACE("Hi Gennnne\nHope","n+","n")
```

Produces:

```
Hi Gene\nHope
```

How do I remove repeating instances of special characters with a single instance of the special character in `Google Sheets`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Edit**

Just found easier way:

`=REGEXREPLACE("Hi Gene\n\n\n\n\nHope","(\\n)+","\\n")`

---

### **Original solution**

Thy this formula:

`=REGEXREPLACE(A1,REPT(F2,(len(A1)-len(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\\n","")))/2),"\\n")`

Put your text in A1.

**How it works**

It's workaround, we want to use final formula like this:

`REGEXREPLACE("Hi Gene\n\n\n\n\nHope","\\n+\\n+\\n+\\n+\\n+","\\n")`

First target is to find, how many times to repeat `\\n+`:

`=(len(F1)-len(REGEXREPLACE(F1,F2,F3)))/2`

Then just combine RegEx.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't think about trying parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en

REGEXREPLACE(text, regular_expression, replacement)

The problem seems to be how it interprets the "text". If I put this in a cell `REGEXREPLACE("Hi Gene\n\n\n\n\nHope","","")`
the output is `Hi Gene\n\n\n\n\nHope` as well.

If I place the text in a cell by itself with proper newlines and have this `REGEXREPLACE(A1, "(\n)\n*", "$1")` it works.

Note I could not just do `s/\n+/\n/` as it still does not interpret the newline notation as anything special. It would just output \n instead of a newline.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you don't need to double escape the newlines, e.g. just search for `\n`:

```
REGEXREPLACE("Hi Gene\n\n\n\n\nHope", "\n+", "\n")
```

When you replace `\\n` you are searching for the literal text `\n`, rather than newline.

Comment: except that it doesn't even find the `\n` if I don't double escape. I can at least find the `\\n` and replace it with `\\n`, but it does a one to one.

Comment: From what I saw in other SO answers, you want to be using `\n` to match a newline (and `\s` to match a space, etc.).  If I'm mistaken, please correct me.

Comment: You are correct, I am just saying it doesn't work when I do what you suggested. I have to escape the `\` for it to work properly. Max provided a solution that works.